# Where would I learn more about interpreting network packets?

Tags: sockets, packet

I'm working on a personal project. It's to recreate server software for the game "Chu Chu Rocket" for the Sega Dreamcast. Its' servers went down in 2004 I believe. My approach is to use dnsmasq to change the originl hostname that the game originally connected to, to my own system. With a DC-PC server set up, I have done just that, now instead of it looking up a non-existent dns record, it connects to my computer which will eventually run the server software. I've used tshark (cli wireshark) to capture what's going on between the client (dreamcast) and the server (my computer). The problem is, I'm getting data, but I'm not sure how to interpret it, I don't know what it's saying, but I'm sure it can be done because private PSO servers were created, those are far more complex.

Very simply, where would I go about learning how to interpret data packets, and possibly creating packets that will respond to such queries from the client?

Thanks,
Dragos240

Comment: its pretty hard to do without having seen the unit interact with a real server

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the source code for the server software on your PC, then that is the best place to look.

Otherwise, all you can do is look at the protocol, compare runs, and make notes of similarities and differences.  With any luck, the protocol won't be encrypted.